# Wordpress crashes when I click add a new plugin after uninstalling a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently uninstalled the plugin [SEO Facebook Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-facebook-comments/)

Since then when I click on add new plugin I get this error,

```
Warning: require_once(D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-admin\includes\list-table.php on line 42

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php' (include_path='D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-content\plugins\google-analyticator\google-api-php-client\src;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-admin\includes\list-table.php on line 42
```

I've looked for this error on google and this site although I cannot seem to find anyone else with this error?

Can anyone help me get past this?

I understand it may be a  explicit PHP error but I am not too sure on how to fix it,

Answer (score 1):

The error is within another plugin that you have installed.

The second line shows the actual crash

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php' (include_path='D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-content\plugins\google-analyticator\google-api-php-client\src;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Dropbox\htdocs\bcu\wp-admin\includes\list-table.php on line 42
```

The plugin is named `google analyticator` and there is a problem with getting data by the looks of things.

Try de-activating the plugin and seeing if you can then add plugins after.

If that is the problem, try uninstalling the plugin, downloading the latest version and then installing that. If there is still a problem with that plugin, then you will have to report it to the creators and look for an alternative.